# How to hyperlink to files relative to the current file with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

I cannot get relative links to files to work when using:

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
```

I can only get the following to work:

```
\href{file://full-path/filename}{text}
```

I have tried the following variations:

```
\href{filename}{text}
\href{./filename}{text}
\href{full-path/filename}{text}
\href{file://./filename}{text}
```

Do I need to configure any options for `hyperref`?

Is it possible to set a path for the current document?

Is it possible to have the path set at compile time?

Comment: For internet addresses, the starting directory has to be set using \hyperbaseurl

Comment: I think \hyperbaseurl is doing what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments

Comment: @StefanPinnow  "I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments" --- Does that mean that if somebody posts an answer based on the comment, this question will be saved?  I wonder why one wants to close the question instead of posting such an answer . . .  I'm willing to post such an answer because the answer is useful.

Comment: @Ryo, since the question *is* already closed you shouldn't be able to write an answer ... But you could vote to reopen it with the reason to write one. But the question would be if the OP would accept it after that long time (haven't checked his activity on this site). But you could give it a try ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for your prompt response. 1) How does one vote? 2) How is it important whether the OP accepts the answer or not?  (I just want this question to stay with an answer, as a record for future users.) 3) Why is it currently classified as "off topic"?  As far as I can tell, it's right on topic of LaTeX.